# 2 right-angled Triangles with sides $a,b,c$ and $1/a,1/b,1/c$. The first has twice the area of the second, what is the perimeter of the first?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

The question in full:

> The triangle *T* has side lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$, whilst triangle *U* has side lengths $1/a$, $1/b$, and $1/c$. Both triangles are right-angled and *T* has twice the area of *U*. What is the perimeter of *T* ?

I can calculate what $b$ is, but cannot get any further. Any help would be appreciated.

How I calculate $b$: If we assume that $a$ is the shortest side of *T*, and that $b$ is the other side of the right-angle. Then $c$ must be the hypotenuse, and therefore longest side. Therefore, on *U*, $\dfrac{1}{c}$ must now be the shortest side,  $\dfrac{1}{a}$ is the longest and $\dfrac{1}{b}$ is the "middle".

Lets call *A* the opposite angle of $a$ and *F* the opposite of $\dfrac{1}{c}$.

Using sohcahtoa we can then deduce that $$\sin{A} = \dfrac{a}{c}$$ and $$\sin {F} = \frac{\dfrac{1}{c}}{\dfrac{1}{a}} = \frac{a}{c}$$ therefore the triangles are similar. Also because we are given that $$A(T) = 2\cdot A(U)$$ we know that $a=\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{2}$ and $b=\frac{1}{b}\sqrt{2}$. the latter then allows us to calculate $b$, which is is the 4th root of 2.

Other worthy things to note: Using $$\text{Area of triangle} = \dfrac{1}{2} \:(\text{base} \times \text{height})$$ we get $$A(T)= \frac{1}{2}(ab)$$ and $$A(U) = \frac{1}{2bc}$$ therefore $$b^2 = \frac{2}{ac}$$ Also, since the triangles are similar, the ratio of $a/b$ must be the same as $(1/c) / (1/b)$ , thus $b^2 = ac$.  Combining these gives $ac = 2 / ac$.

I have a feeling that I need to use the sine rule or cosine rule to get further, but can't quite get something that is solvable (other than $(a^4)/2 + (a^2)/\sqrt{2} = 1$)

Comment: With "other than " you have a^2 an so all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a< b<c$ and start with the equations:
$$
a^2+b^2=c^2,\quad \frac1{c^2}+\frac1{b^2}=\frac1{a^2}.\tag1
$$

Elimnation of $c$ results in the equation:
$$
b^4-a^4=a^2b^2.
$$
Resolving this quadratic (with respect to $a^2$) equation and using $c^2=a^2+b^2$ one obtains:
$$
a^2=\frac{\sqrt5-1}2b^2,\quad c^2=\frac{\sqrt5+1}2b^2.\tag2
$$
Observe $a^2c^2=b^4$.

Let the ratio of the areas be $\lambda^4$ with $\lambda>0$. Then we have:
$$
\lambda^4=ab^2c=b^4\implies b=\lambda.
$$

Using $(2)$ to compute $a$ and $c$ one finally obtains for the perimeter the value:
$$
\lambda\left[\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5-1}2}+1+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt5+1}2}\right]
=\lambda\left[1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt5}\right].
$$

In your case $\lambda=2^\frac14$.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you "resolved the sqaure equation" to get (2) please? Once I have understood that, I understand how to get the correct answer

Comment: @allanmb Resolving the square equation means that you fix $b$ and treat $a^2$ as unknown $x$ in the equation $x^2+b^2x-b^4=0$. Should I add this to answer?

Comment: Ah ok, using the quadratic root equation?

Comment: I see. English is not my native language. I have meant quadratic equation and will correct it now. Thank you for this comment.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is much appreciated :-)

Comment: I'm still not quite getting the same result you do in (2). If I rearrange $$b^4-a^4=a^2 b^2$$ to become $$a^4 +a^2 b^2 - b^4=0$$ Then using the quadratic formula where the a,b,c of the quadratic formula evaluate to: $1$, $\sqrt{2}$, $-1$. That gives me 2 possible roots for $a^2$ ?

Comment: A quadratic equation can have at most two distinct roots. Particularly the equation $$x^2+b^2x-b^4=0$$ with $(A,B,C)=(1,b^2,-b^4)$ has the roots $$\frac{-1\pm\sqrt5}2b^2.$$ One of them is negative and should be rejected.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. My mistake was the last root. I had it as $-1$ and not $-b^4$.  I have the solution from start to end now.